# Deprecated method publisher.destroy() opentok?

Tags: android

After updating tolkbox to 2.19.1 the method is deprecated publisher destroy(), documentation talks about the finalize method, but has no execution example?

Answer (score 0):

Finalize methods are features of the Java language.  Its called when an object is deleted by the garbage collector.  You don't call it yourself, the language calls it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the publisher.destroy() use this method publisherKit.destroy().

[image: Destroy() defined.]